# What is the probability of an empty convex $k$-gon among many given points?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, discrete-geometry, convexity, enumerative-combinatorics

Given a finite number of points in the plane in general position, call a convex subset *empty* if its hull doesn't contain any other of the points.

> For a big number $n$ of randomly distributed points in the plane (or in the unit disk, which should have the same outcome), what is the probability $p_k$ for a subset of a given order $k$ to be an empty convex $k$-gon?

[Erdös has shown that](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9dcb/bfa44b5d9fb0f4fde8db5b4754e48a5a4d4c.pdf) if $n>n_0(k)$ is big enough and $n$ points are in general position in the plane, there always exists a convex $k$-gon among them. But in the same article it is pointed out that for $k>6$, an *empty* convex $k$-gon does not need to exist.
Intuitively, we should however have $p_k>0$ for all $k\geqslant3$. If so, then we may also ask:

> What about the asymptotics of $p_k$ as $k$ grows?

The quoted article has a section (2.2) about counting empty convex $k$-gons. But it seems to me that the number $h_k(n)$ refers to the *minimal possible* number of empty convex $k$-gons among $n$ points, otherwise it makes no sense.
On the other hand, the present question with $p_k$ is about the average number instead. I have no idea how to find even $p_3$.

Comment: Here is a variation which may be of interest, and perhaps more tractable.  Start with a finite grid (square or triangular, with some symmetry). Define a probability distribution of displacement: for each point on the grid, assume an epsilon radius disk centered at that grid point, and define a distribution of interest on that disk. What is p_k given this arrangement? This might be in the physics literature.  Gerhard "Or Some Similar Lattice-Gas Model" Paseman, 2019.09.12.

Answer (score 4):

This may be a start, specialized to quadrilaterals:

> Fabila-Monroy, Ruy, Clemens Huemer, and Dieter Mitsche. "Empty non-convex and convex four-gons in random point sets." *Studia Scientiarum Mathematicarum Hungarica* 52, no. 1 (2015): 52-64.
>   [Semantics Scholar PDF download](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ab57/79aca5ed1fae4136c9ea85496c526491d38c.pdf).

"We show that the expected number of empty
non-convex four-gons with vertices from $S$ is$12n^2 \log n + o(n^2\log n)$, and
the expected number of empty convex four-gons with vertices from $S$ is
$\Theta(n^2)$."

---

[image: Fig1]

          

<sup>Fig. 1.</sup>

---